# Cuda compile error when "cuMemGetAddressRange" exists

Tags: c++, cuda

Here comes the sample codes:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    unsigned char* cu_test;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&cu_test, 3200);

    CUdeviceptr pbase;
    size_t psize;
    CUresult res = cuMemGetAddressRange(&pbase, &psize, (CUdeviceptr)cu_test);
    printf("cu_img_yuv size: %ld", psize);

    return 0;
}
```

While it throws error when compiling whatever the cuda version is(tested from 11.3 to 11.5):

```
$ nvcc main.cu -o main
/tmp/tmpxft_0000e288_00000000-11_main.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_0000e288_00000000-6_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `cuMemGetAddressRange_v2'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Can someone help pointing out what the problem is plz?

Comment: If you are using the driver API, you will have to explicitly link the driver API library

Comment: @talonmies Cool! Added -lcuda when compiling via `nvcc main.cu -lcuda -o main`, now it works !

Comment: Great. Please add that as an answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message:

```
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

denotes that it is a linking error ( see `ld` ).

To see this is the case, you can run

```
nvcc -c main.cu -o main.o
```

and you will not get any error. This is the source-code compilation step!

**Solution:**

You need to explicitly specify linkage with the CUDA driver stub library:

```
nvcc main.cu -o main -lcuda
```

That is because `cuMemGetAddressRange()` is part of the CUDA Driver API, not the CUDA runtime API.

**NOTE**: you did not `cudaFree()` the allocated memory, you might want to fix this!

**Edit:** (credit to @talonmies comment) You do not have to explicitly link against the CUDA runtime library (`-lcudart`), because `nvcc` will automatically link against it.

Comment: nvcc will automagically link the runtime library, that is not required. The missing driver library stub is the only problem

Comment: Okay, i didn't know that! Is this always the case, or?

Comment: Yes always the case. It would be good if you correct your answer